# Basis of free abelian group tensor $\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $E$ be a free abelian group of rank $n$, then $E\otimes \mathbb R$ becomes an $\mathbb R$-vector space.

If {$e_1, e_2\dots, e_n$} is a basis for $E$, will {$e_1\otimes1, e_2\otimes1,\dots ,e_n\otimes1$} be basis for $E\otimes\mathbb R$?
 It generates  $E\otimes\mathbb R$ clearly, but will they be linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n$ elements in a $n$-dimensional vector-space, that generate the vector space. Clearly they are linearly independent then.

Comment: Then why is it $n$-dimensional?

Comment: Use the fact that tensor product commutes with direct sums:

$E \otimes \mathbb R \cong (\bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb Z) \otimes \mathbb R \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n (\mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb R) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb R$